# Example of ASP.NET Core web app using CSOM with user access token

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, .net-7.0, csom

I haven't found any up to date example of ASP.NET Core app with Microsoft Identity authentication calling Sharepoint online CSOM API on behalf of logged in user.

The [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard#using-modern-authentication-with-csom-for-net-standard) only provides sample for username/password authentication.

How do I authenticate against sharepoint online (in the same tenant) when using CSOM?

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to following code

```
AuthenticationManager authManager = new AuthenticationManager();
using (var context = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(URI))
{
    context.Load(context.Web, web => web.Title);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Your site title is: " + context.Web.Title);
}
```

Add SharePointPnPCoreOnline Nuget package in your console application. After that, you will be able to login to the SPO env. Basically, this will give you a prompt to enter your details in a browser window.

Comment: This is not console application. This is ASP.NET Core app.